# replacing first row of selected column from each group with 0

Tags: pandas

Existing df :

```
Id      status      value

A1       clear        23
A1       in-process   50
A1       done         20
B1       start        2
B1        end         30
```

Expected df :

```
Id      status      value

A1       clear        0
A1       in-process   50
A1       done         20
B1       start        0
B1        end         30
```

looking to replace first value of each group with 0

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) for duplicated values, set first duplicate by inverse mask by `~` with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df.loc[~df['Id'].duplicated(), 'value'] = 0
print (df)
   Id      status  value
0  A1       clear      0
1  A1  in-process     50
2  A1        done     20
3  B1       start      0
4  B1         end     30
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be as follows:

- Compare the values for each row in `df.Id` with the next row, combining [`Series.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) with [`Series.ne`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html). This will return a boolean `Series` with `True` for each first row of a new `Id` value.
- Next, use [`df.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to select only rows with `True` for column `value` and assign `0`.

```
df.loc[df.Id.ne(df.Id.shift()), 'value'] = 0

print(df)

   Id      status  value
0  A1       clear      0
1  A1  in-process     50
2  A1        done     20
3  B1       start      0
4  B1         end     30
```

N.B. this approach assumes that the "groups" in `Id` are *sorted* (as they seem to be, indeed). If this is not the case, you could use `df.sort_values('Id', inplace=True)` first, but if that is necessary, the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74067361/18470692) by [@jezrael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2901002/jezrael) will be faster, surely.

Comment: And maybe you can add difference with my answer ;)

Comment: @jezrael: you don't find this answer different? I'm suggesting `df.Id.ne(df.Id.shift())`, you're suggesting `~df['Id'].duplicated()`.

Comment: yes, I think explain difference ;)

Comment: @jezrael: of course, your approach has the additional benefit of not caring whether `df.Id` is sorted (though, in this particular case, the ids seem sorted). And I just learning from mozway that having to sort is quite expensive :).

Comment: seems not understand each other. First no problem with your answer, it create consecutive first values, not duplicates like me.

Answer (score 0):

```
df1.mask(~df1.Id.duplicated(),0)
```